# What's the parse function to this Json?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

```
"results": [
      {
         "result_index": 0,
         "results": [
            {
               "final": true,
               "alternatives": [
                  {
                     "transcript": "THE TEXT ",
                     "confidence": 0.2958
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status": "completed"
```

I want the value of transcript in this Json, basically i want :THE TEXT

The parse i tried and didn't work :

```
def parse(obj):
    text=[]
    if 'results' in obj:
        results = obj['results']
        for result in results:
            if 'results' in results:
                results = results['results']
                if 'alternatives' in result:
                    alternatives = result['alternatives']
                    assert len(alternatives) == 1
                    alternative = alternatives[0]
                    text.append(alternative['transcript'])
    return ' '.join(text).lstrip().rstrip()
```

What would the correct parse function to use be

Comment: What does *"didn't work"* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the json package? It'd make your life easier, use:

```
import json
```

Then, from thereon:

```
data2 = json.loads('''{"results": [
      {
         "result_index": 0,
         "results": [
            {
               "final": true,
               "alternatives": [
                  {
                     "transcript": "THE TEXT ",
                     "confidence": 0.2958
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status": "completed"}''')

print(data2['results'][0]['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])
```

First of all, your JSON isn't even valid, you have to enclose it in curly brackets. Next, as JSON.loads expects a string, you have to wrap it in `'''`. 
Another way'd be that you declare your JSON as a var, then call `new_var = JSON.dumps(your_json_var)`, and then `JSON.loads(new_var)`, and then call the same print function as above.

Comment: It didn't work. TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: oh okey but that gives me only 1 element, what if i had 100.(that's basically why i use ifs).

Comment: You'd have to dynamically change the indexes in/of arrays in your print function, that's pretty much it as far as I understand what you'd be doing, and I'd go for the second way which I've described for assigning the JSON.